# What does ' #period ' mean in Verilog code?

Tags: verilog, vivado, quartus

[image]

What does `#period` indicate or mean in Verilog in general terms?  I have posted the image just as an example.

Comment: Timing control which is not synthesisable.

Answer (score 2):

`#` is a timing control that can be used to add a delay in the simulator.

In your example, the duration of the delay is specified by `timescale` * `period`.

`period` has no special meaning. It's simply a `localparam` that holds the constant expression 20:

- `localparam period = 20;`

According to the comment, the timescale has a unit of 1ns.

The timescale configuration should look something like this:

- `timescale 1ns/1ps

Therefore the expression after `#period;` is delayed by 1ns * 20 = 20ns.

Answer (score 1):

`#period` can have different meanings depending on the context where it is used.

In the example provided, it is a *delay event control* placed in front of an empty procedural statement. That means it suspends the currently executing process for 20 time units until proceeding to the statement that follows it.

`#period` can also be used

- as a gate delay: `not #period (out,int);`
- continuous assignment delay: `assign #period A = B + C;`
- as a parameter value override in a module instance:

```
mymod #period mm(...);
...
module mymod #(P=0)(...);
endmodule
```